# adding mysql columns for ouput in csv php?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

im trying to add table data from mysql to csv and output them to browser using php.

PHP:

```
$rows = $t->db->query("SELECT * from Animals");
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));
while ($row = $rows->result_array()) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

but im getting error:

> Message: Array to string conversion

on the line where the while loop is, i don't seem to see where the problem is.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried checking what `$rows->result_array()` returns?

Comment: What is $t in *$t->db->query*? Shouldn't it be *$this* ?

Comment: Put here result from `print_r( $row)` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[result_array()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)** returns all the results, which is an array of arrays.

Change

```
while ($row = $rows->result_array()) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

To

```
foreach ($rows->result_array() as $row) {
  fputcsv($output, $row);
}
```